# What does the oldmap actually do here? Can someone explain

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-lightning

This is a code to create a new task when stage is inserted or updated to Closed Won

```
trigger ClosedOpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {

List<Task> tl = new List<Task>();

for(Opportunity op : Trigger.new) {


    if(Trigger.isInsert) {
        if(Op.StageName == 'Closed Won') {
            tl.add(new Task(Subject = 'Follow Up Test Task', WhatId = op.Id));
        }
    }


    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        if(Op.StageName == 'Closed Won' 
        && Op.StageName != Trigger.oldMap.get(op.Id).StageName) {
            tl.add(new Task(Subject = 'Follow Up Test Task', WhatId = op.Id));
        }
    }       
}

if(tl.size()>0) {        
    insert tl;        
}    
}
```

Here, what does  && Op.StageName != Trigger.oldMap.get(op.Id).StageName) do? Why do we use oldMap here?

Comment: It used to compare whether the `StageName` is same or different between before update and after update. In your case, only the Opportunity is changed from other stage to "CloseWon" will create a new Task.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger.newMap is the map of IDs of new object values. Available in insert, update, and undelete triggers, and 'new' records can only be modified in before triggers.

Trigger.oldMap is the map of IDs of old object values.  Available in update and delete triggers only.

```
if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
    // Iterate updated opportunities
    for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
        // Get the opportunity before update
        Opportunity oldOpp = Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id);

        // Check if a value changed
        if (o.Some_Value__c == oldOpp.Some_Value__c) {
             System.debug('Value did not change.');
        } else {
             System.debug('Value changed!');
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I could have used Trigger.newMap instead of Trigger.new but I'd be looping through Trigger.newMap.values() instead - with the same end result.  newMap is just a convenient way of getting the bulkified data in map form instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

We use old map to compare with the new value of the Some_Value__c custom field. If the two values differ then the field value has changed. Of course, if you read the code in the two if branches, this is obvious.

Comment: should be rather a comment